# Load GoogleMap Async with USGSOverlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, asynchronous

I'm currently working with Browserify for my JS Files. I got an error when i try to load GoogleMap Api aSync and apply USGSOverlay for custom image overlay.

I followed this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays.

Everything work well for a simple GoogleMaps but as soon as i apply the USGSOverlay, i got multiple error like : Uncaught TypeError: this.draw is not a function WM15838:1

It must be how i call my function.. ? Here the code :

```
var $ = require('jquery');

var overlay;
var map;
var USGSOverlay;

//map_area is defined inline, but for this post...
var map_area = new Array('45.684994,-73.731739','45.684616,-73.732816','45.684450,-73.732558','45.684659,-73.732002','45.684832,-73.731602');

window.launchMap = function() {
    initialize();
}

USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';

    // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.image_;
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.appendChild(img);

    this.div_ = div;

    // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};
// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
};

function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

    // Initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;

    // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
    // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
    // method so we'll leave it null for now.
    this.div_ = null;

    // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
    this.setMap(map);
}

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

    // We use the south-west and north-east
    // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
    // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
    // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

function initialize() {
    USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.684163, -73.733305),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var marker_pin = "/images/site/Pin.png";
    var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(45.678510, -73.747798);
    var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(45.692415, -73.718118);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

    // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
    var srcImage = 'map.png';

    // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
    // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
    overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "Chargement..."
    });


    var areaCoords = [];

    if (map_area.length > 0) {
        for    (i = 0; i < map_area.length; i++) {
            areaCoords[i] = new Array();

            for    (j = 0; j < map_area[i].length; j++) {
                coord = map_area[i][j].split(',');
                areaCoords[i][j] = new google.maps.LatLng(coord[0], coord[1]);
            }

            polygonMap = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: areaCoords[i],
                strokeColor: '#ff2205',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: '#ff2205',
                fillOpacity: 0
            });

            polygonMap.setMap(map);
        }
        // Add a listener for the click event.
        /*google.maps.event.addListener(polygonMap, 'click', function() {
        });    */
    }

    $('.block_unit').each(function(index, element) {

        var _lat = $(this).find('.address').data('lat');
        var _lng = $(this).find('.address').data('lng');
        latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(_lat, _lng)
        $(this).next('.map_popup').find('.text').html($(this).find('.block__title').html());
        var info = $(this).next('.map_popup').html();


        //info.find('.text').html($(this).find('.block__title').html());

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latLng,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker_pin)
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: info});
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
      '&signed_in=true&callback=launchMap';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: What is `map_area`?  `Uncaught ReferenceError: map_area is not defined`.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: map_area is a var defined inline on the page and used to provide coords and trace a path. Yep, i missed to provide a tested and readable example of the issue.. here i made the correction. merci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `USGSOverlay` depends on the Google Maps Javascript API v3.  You can't define it until after that code is loaded.  Define it inside your `launchMap` or `initialize` functions.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gj1fxzmq/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var overlay;
var map;
var USGSOverlay;
//map_area is defined inline, but for this post...
var map_area = new Array('45.684994,-73.731739', '45.684616,-73.732816', '45.684450,-73.732558', '45.684659,-73.732002', '45.684832,-73.731602');

window.launchMap = function() {
  /** @constructor */
  USGSOverlay = function(bounds, image, map) {

    // Initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;

    // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
    // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
    // method so we'll leave it null for now.
    this.div_ = null;

    // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
    this.setMap(map);
  };
  USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';

    // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.image_;
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.appendChild(img);

    this.div_ = div;

    // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
  };
  // The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
  // we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
  USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
  };


  USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {

    // We use the south-west and north-east
    // coordinates of the overlay to peg it to the correct position and size.
    // To do this, we need to retrieve the projection from the overlay.
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    // Retrieve the south-west and north-east coordinates of this overlay
    // in LatLngs and convert them to pixel coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to resize the div.
    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
  };

  initialize();
};

function initialize() {


  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.684163, -73.733305),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var marker_pin = "/images/site/Pin.png";
  var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(45.678510, -73.747798);
  var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(45.692415, -73.718118);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

  // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
  // var srcImage = 'map.png';
  var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/';
  srcImage += 'examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';
  // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
  // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
  overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Chargement..."
  });


  var areaCoords = [];

  if (map_area.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < map_area.length; i++) {
      areaCoords[i] = [];

      for (j = 0; j < map_area[i].length; j++) {
        coord = map_area[i][j].split(',');
        areaCoords[i][j] = new google.maps.LatLng(coord[0], coord[1]);
      }

      polygonMap = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: areaCoords[i],
        strokeColor: '#ff2205',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#ff2205',
        fillOpacity: 0
      });

      polygonMap.setMap(map);
    }
    // Add a listener for the click event.
    /*google.maps.event.addListener(polygonMap, 'click', function() {
    });    */
  }

  $('.block_unit').each(function(index, element) {

    var _lat = $(this).find('.address').data('lat');
    var _lng = $(this).find('.address').data('lng');
    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(_lat, _lng);
    $(this).next('.map_popup').find('.text').html($(this).find('.block__title').html());
    var info = $(this).next('.map_popup').html();


    //info.find('.text').html($(this).find('.block__title').html());

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latLng,
      icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker_pin)
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: info
      });
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp' +
    '&signed_in=true&callback=launchMap';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="order_list"></div>
<div id="product-list-display"></div>
```